# SQL and PHP check if a value is equal to something

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was just wondering how I can check if a value in a mysql database is equal to something.The database connection is fine, Here's my code. If you could help it would be much appreciated.

```
$array = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM users");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($array);
if(in_array($username,$result['username'],TRUE)){
    echo "$username <br/> ";
}else{
    echo "Failed";
}
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'xxx'`.

Comment: You can't mix `mysqli` and `mysql` functions in the same code.

Comment: Time to check out [a basic SQL tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/) I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example using mysqli and cleaned up:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE fieldname = data";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if ($row['username']) {
    echo "$username <br/> ";
 } else {
    echo "Failed";
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what the `WHERE` clause is used for.  Here's how to do this using prepared statements.

```
$sql = mysqli_prepare($connect, 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?');
if($sql !== FALSE){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, 's', $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);

    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result();
    if($result !== FALSE){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        echo $row['username'];
    }
}
else{
    die(mysqli_error($connect));
}
```

P.S. `mysqli_stmt_get_result` requires the [MySQLnd driver](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use a prepared statement to substitute into the query.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1) {
    echo "$username<br/>";
} else {
    echo "Failed";
}
```